# FOSRestBundle: Pass additional variables to the Twig template

Tags: php, rest, symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm using the same action to deal with an `html` and a `json` response, just suffixing the later one route with `.json`.

The `json` is working with no problem, but when the response is `html` I need to pass an additional variable to the `Twig` template, and I don't know and I don't find how to do it. At the moment, my code is:

```
// $entity = get my data;

$name = 'foo';

$view = $this->view($entity, 200)
   ->setTemplate('MyBundle:MyController:myTemplate.html.twig')
   ->setTemplateVar('entity')
   ;

return $this->handleView($view);
```

How can I pass `$name` to `myTemplate.html.twig`? What I would need is something like:

```
//...
->setTemplate('MyBundle:MyController:myTemplate.html.twig', array('name' => $name))
//...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got the response opening an [issue in FosRestBundle github page](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/issues/299).

At the moment, there is no straightforward way, but the following procedure will work:

1) Add `_format` option with `html` and `json` values, respectively, in the route defaults:

```
defaults: { _controller: myBundle:myController:myAction, _format: html } #or json
```

2) Add `$_format` as the first parameter of the action signature:

```
public function myActionAction($_format, $any_other_paramer)
```

3) Conditionally add more variables to the Twig template:

```
if ($this->get('fos_rest.view_handler')->isFormatTemplating($_format)) {
  $view->setData(array('name' => $name, 'entity' => $view->getData()));
}
```